# Using Laravel 5 Join Query on Eloquent Model to return results in a specific order

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-5.3

I am trying to execute a join query which would return an object which contains values from 2 tables in the correct order.

1st table(staff):

**staff_id          staff_name**

v001                   Jane Rocks
v002                   Mike Dean

2nd table(loan):
**staff_id           staff_loan** 
v002                   $400
v001                   $200

My Eloquent Model join query:

```js
$name= staff::join('loan','loan.staff_id','=','staff.staff_id')->pluck('staff.staff_name');
return([loan.staff_id,staff.staff_name,loan.staff_loan])
```

The result i'm presently getting:
[v002, Jane Rocks, $400], 
[v001, Mike Dean $200]

The result I want: 
[v002, Mike Dean, $400], 
[v001, Jane Rocks $200]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you are accessing your collection, not the table values directly.

**Update 1**

I built your table and query in raw MySQL and everything checks out.  The raw query would be:

```
SELECT a.staff_id, a.staff_name, b.staff_loan
FROM `staff` a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM `loan`
) b ON a.staff_id = b.staff_id;
```

Translating this into a Laravel query:

```
$names = Staff::join('loan', 'loan.staff_id', '=', 'staff.staff_id')
    ->select('staff.*', 'loan.staff_loan')
    ->get();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I'm using vuejs to echo out my response. Isn't there a way I can tie the way the staff_name is pulled from the staff table to the staff_id in the loans table. So that I can loop through the array and echo them out?

Comment: That is exactly what is happening.  You will get all columns from both the staff and loan tables linked by staff_id.  If you want to use this in a vue component then you have to simply pass the object to your view and insert it into your cue component.

Comment: But why is it still just putting the staff_name into an array in the order that it appears in the staff table and not how it appears in the  loan table. I'm still getting the [v002, v001],[Jane Rocks,Mike Dean], [$400,$200] instead of  [v002, v001],[Mike Dean,Jane Rocks], [$400,$200]